# Problems with maven-release-plugin and expressions

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, maven-3, maven-release-plugin

We're trying to release our project with the *maven-release-plugin* on *Jenkins*.

Unfortunately we're getting this error:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.5.2:prepare
>   (default-cli) on project our-project: The artifact (our-group:our-parser)
>   requires a different version (1.3) than what is found
>   (${our-parent.version}) for the expression (our-parser.version) in the project
>   (our-group:our-project). -> [Help 1]

As I can see from the log files the variable `our-parent.version` has been replaced with `1.3`. `our-parser.version` references the variable `our-parent.version`. So everything should be fine. Why do we get this error then?

---

Here is our POM:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <!-- some stuff -->
    <properties>
        <our-parent.version>1.3-SNAPSHOT</our-parent.version>
        <our-parser.version>${our-parent.version}</our-parser.version>
    </properties>
    <!-- some stuff -->
    <modules>
        <!-- some stuff -->
        <module>our-parser</module>
    </modules>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <!-- some stuff -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>groupId</groupId>
                <artifactId>our-parser</artifactId>
                <version>${our-parser.version}</version>
            </dependency>           
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
</project>
```

Comment: could we have some part of yours poms ?

Comment: @vincent I've attached the relevant snippets.

Comment: like @bmargulies says, maven release plugin will change the version of your pom, not the value of your own properties. And it will fail if you have a dependency in a snapshot version

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps:

```
    <our-parent.version>engine-1.3-SNAPSHOT</our-parent.version>
```

Should be

```
${project.version}
```

?

Answer (score 1):

dont use properties use version directly

```
<properties>
   <our-parent.version>1.3-SNAPSHOT</our-parent.version>
   <our-parser.version>${our-parent.version}</our-parser.version>
</properties>

....

<dependency>
    <groupId>groupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>our-parser</artifactId>
    <version>1.3</version>
</dependency>a
```